# Using sherlock to check for plagiarism through python subprocess module

Tags: python, subprocess, plagiarism-detection

When i write on terminal:

```
./sherlock *.txt
```

it works

but when I try to do the same using python subprocess like

```
import subprocess 
subprocess.call(['./sherlock','*.txt'])


import subprocess
subprocess.call('./sherlock','*.txt',shell=True)

import subprocess
subprocess.call('./sherlock','*.txt',shell=False)
```

Neither of this is working please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shell expand `*`, `subprocess.call` does not. Expand the `*` yourself using `glob.glob`.

And beside that, the argument that represent the command to be issued should be a list or a string object (not multiple arguments).

```
import glob
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['./sherlock'] + glob.glob('*.txt'), shell=False)
```

Comment: This is especially true on Windows, where the shell doesn't expand wildcards, so using `shell=True` won't even help there.

Comment: you could omit `shell=False`; it is default.